# My app stops unexpectedly when I switch to another fragment through bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I have just started learning layouts and basic UI elements of **Android Studio** as well as how it organizes the files which are `drawable, layouts, strings, activities` etc.

So, I have managed to add a basic `navigation` widget to one `activity` that has 5 navigation items by following some youtube tutorial. The only `navigation item` that responds to a tap is the first one which is the **dashboard**. The rest returns an "**Unfortunately the app has stopped**" dialog.

Here's the code on my `Activity.java`

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class StudentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_dashboard: //this works
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                    builder1.setMessage("Dashboard To.");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);
                    builder1.show(); // I'm able to see the dialog here

                    setTitle("Dashboard");
                    DashboardFragment dashboard_fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout,dashboard_fragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_learn: //this doesn't work
                    try {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                        builder2.setMessage("Learn To.");
                        builder2.setCancelable(true);
                        builder2.show(); //dialog doesn't even show up

                        setTitle("Learn");
                        DashboardFragment learn_fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction manager1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        manager1.replace(R.id.frameLayout, learn_fragment);
                        manager1.commit();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                        errorDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                        errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        errorDialog.show();
                    }

                    return true;
           }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

And below is how my `navigation.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="Dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_learn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_openbook2"
        android:title="Learn" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_play"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_game2"
        android:title="Play" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_review"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shapes"
        android:title="Review" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_user2"
        android:title="My Profile" />

</menu>
```

I have verified that all `drawable` icons **are present and are in lower case names**.

I made sure that correct import of `import android.app.FragmentTransaction;` is included. I did some research and found that there is also an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` which is not the correct one.

Build was successful and I'm able to launch the app using **Nox** emulator.There are no messages in **Message Gradle Build** window.

[image]
[image]

What could be the cause? Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance.
EDIT: 
Here's the error I get when I tap on the 2nd navigation item.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a004b (com.example.peace:id/frameLayout) for fragment LearnFragment{4bbf1c20 #1 id=0x7f0a004b}
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
```

Here's the `LearnFragment.java`

```
package com.example.peace.cai;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LearnFragment extends Fragment {


    public LearnFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_learn, container, false);
    }
}
```

And here the `fragment_learn.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.peace.cai.LearnFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error logs ?

Comment: @Chitra I've just found where to get the error logs by going to Help > Show log in explorer. Is that the error logs you need? Sorry, I'm quite new. I've spent hours trying to figure out what went wrong. The error logs is dated yesterday and has 40-50s of lines.

Comment: I answered your Question ,Look into this @p3ace

Comment: @Chithra I've added the logs.

Comment: Can you post the `LearnFragment` and its corresponding layout file ?

Comment: @Chithra I added the `LearnFragment` and the `fragment_learn.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You are using same fragment for both of the bottom menu buttons. You  are calling same fragment from both bottomNav buttons only reference is changed.

Change `DashboardFragment learn_fragment = new DashboardFragment();` here, `DashboardFragment()` to `LearnFragment learn_fragment = new LearnFragment ();` or what you have.

Below is your Code :

```
 case R.id.navigation_dashboard: //this works
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Dashboard To.");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                builder1.show(); // I'm able to see the dialog here

                setTitle("Dashboard");
                DashboardFragment dashboard_fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout,dashboard_fragment);
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_learn: //this doesn't work
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                    builder2.setMessage("Learn To.");
                    builder2.setCancelable(true);
                    builder2.show(); //dialog doesn't even show up

                    setTitle("Learn");
                    DashboardFragment learn_fragment = new DashboardFragment(); // Here need to change LearnFragment() 
                    FragmentTransaction manager1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    manager1.replace(R.id.frameLayout, learn_fragment);
                    manager1.commit();
```

Change your fragment `fragment_learn.xml` to `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"   
    tools:context="com.example.peace.cai.LearnFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already replaced the learn fragment. However, It didn't solve the problem though. I am getting an error 

No view found for id 0x7f0a004b (com.example.id/frameLayout) for fragment LearnFragment{4bbf1c20 #1 id=0x7f0a004b

Comment: post you LearnFragment.java  with xml too, by logcat its showing issue of views

Comment: I added the `LearnFragment` and `fragment_learn.xml` I hope you can help me. I need to create the UI for a big project which I'm starting from scratch.

Comment: I'm trying to find the bug @p3ace

Comment: Why are you using  AlertDialog ?

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can get the dialog to show up when a navigation item is tapped. I get the dialog when I tap what's assigned to first `CASE` But the 2nd `CASE` won't show the dialog which clearly shows there's a problem with the code within the 2nd `CASE`

Comment: Remove dialog and put log .
Log.e("DashboardFragment ","DashboardFragment  ");

Comment: change your fragment xml to linearlayout , i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity.java class, in the first case R.id.navigation_dashboard you are replacing whatever was in the container R.id.frameLayout with dashboard_fragment but you are not committing that transaction. In the second case R.id.navigation_learn you are replacing whatever was in the same container R.id.frameLayout with another fragment LearnFragment and doing the commit, so at this time in the same transaction you are trying to push two fragments into same layout and probably this is causing the crash. Fix the issue by committing the first transaction like you do for the second one. See the code below.

```
case R.id.navigation_dashboard: //this works
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                    builder1.setMessage("Dashboard To.");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);
                    builder1.show(); // I'm able to see the dialog here

                    setTitle("Dashboard");
                    DashboardFragment dashboard_fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  transaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout,dashboard_fragment).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_learn: //this doesn't work
                    try {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                        builder2.setMessage("Learn To.");
                        builder2.setCancelable(true);
                        builder2.show(); //dialog doesn't even show up

                        setTitle("Learn");
                        LearnFragment learn_fragment = new LearnFragment ();
                        FragmentTransaction manager1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        manager1.replace(R.id.frameLayout, learn_fragment);
                        manager1.commit();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentActivity.this);
                        errorDialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                        errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        errorDialog.show();
                    }

                    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your fragment.

```
if(getActivity() != null && isAdded) {
  //do your operation
}
```